# How to sort rows of the excel sheet key depends on one of the columns?

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort rows based on the ratings in descending order.

This is the current format of my excel sheet.

```
Minions 2015 6.4
Now You See Me 2013 7.3
Prisoners 2013 8.1
Rumor Has It 1993� 5.4
The Prestige 2006 8.5
The Proposal 2009 6.7
```

I want the output like this:

```
The Prestige 2006 8.5
Prisoners 2013 8.1
Now You See Me 2013 7.3
The Proposal 2009 6.7
Minions 2015 6.4
Rumor Has It 1993� 5.4
```

Comment: it's not very clear how are organized your data, do you get it as a list in python ? Do you have some code to post ?

Comment: Otherwise within excel there is a sort by feature.

Comment: but we still don't know the env, which library is used to connect to sheet etc. Pls, give more details

Comment: Please take some time to read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure that a) you are specific on what you have tried and the difficulties you have faced and b) we are given sufficient information to assist you.

Comment: sorry @Dadep , i am storing each row in list and writing those in .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to read you can use `readlines()`

```
file = open('thefile.txt', 'r')
fileList=file.readlines()
```

then you need to read each element of the list :

```
lines=[]
for i in range(len(fileList)):
    lines.append(fileList[i].split(' '))
```

and use `itemgetter` (`from operator import itemgetter`) to sort "lines":

```
Result=sorted(lines, key=itemgetter(2))
```

And then write in a new file

the all code :

```
from operator import itemgetter


file = open('thefile.txt', 'r')
fileList=file.readlines()

lines=[]
for i in range(len(fileList)):
    lines.append(fileList[i].split(' '))

sortedLines=sorted(lines, key=itemgetter(2))

result=[]

for j in range(len(sortedLines)): 
    result.append(' '.join(sortedLines[j]))


newFile=open("fileSorted.txt", "w")

for j in result: 
    newFile.write("%s\n" % j)
```